# Firestore DocumentReference Type Checking mismatch

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I'm writing the following snippet with the TS compiler option 'strict' enabled, I get a compiler error:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import DocumentReference = firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
...
this.db.collection('users').doc('admin').ref.get()
  .then(snap => {
    const ref: DocumentReference = snap.ref; // TS2322:Type 'DocumentReference' is not assignable to type 'firebase.firestore.DocumentReference'.
  })
```

How can I fix this?

(It's a snippet from an Angular project using AngularFire2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `import DocumentReference = firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;` is wrong.

Try this way:

`import { DocumentReference } from '@firebase/firestore-types';`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks a lot! Seems like I've became a victim of the automatic imports of my IDE.

Comment: Yes, i know, it does that :)

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to fix it and keep the workflow smooth?

Comment: That depends on your text editor / IDE. There are auto import plugins. I have one installed, but as in your case sometimes it imports third-party files incorrect. Haven't tried to fix that yet

Answer (score 0):

For those that are using the modular web SDK, you can import the dependency as such:

```
import { DocumentReference } from 'firebase/firestore`
```

Note that it appears importing directly from `@firebase/firestore-types` is not recommended. See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/firestore-types) for more info.